# TAPI component for .net that works with Win8/Win Srv 2012?

Tags: .net, tapi

Anybody who knows of a TAPI component that works with Windows Server 2012 (and Windows 8)?

I've tried TraySoft AddTapi.Net without any lock :(

Thanks

Mojo

Comment: I use Exceletel Teletools. BUT - could this be an issue with that fact you are using Windows 8? I have Windows 8 and the Avaya TAPI drivers are broken in Windows 8, no incoming calls :( By chance are you using Avaya TAPI drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with the TSPs, and is due to a problem with Microsoft's specification being inconsistent:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/1d9646d9-ea18-4bfa-8214-d017cab97d56/